# Kotlin - Find matching objects in array

Tags: arrays, list, filter, kotlin

Let's say I have an array of strings and I want to get a list with objects that match, such as:

```
var locales=Locale.getAvailableLocales()
val filtered = locales.filter { l-> l.language=="en" }
```

except, instead of a single value I want to compare it with another list, like:

```
val lang = listOf("en", "fr", "es")
```

How do I do that? I'm looking for a one-liner solution without any loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this

```
var locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales()
val filtered = locales.filter { l -> lang.contains(l.language)}
```

As pointed out in comments, you can skip naming the parameter to the lambda, and use `it` keyword to have either of the following:

```
val filtered1 = locales.filter{ lang.contains(it.language) }
val filtered2 = locales.filter{ it.language in lang }
```

Just remember to have a suitable data structure for the languages, so that the `contains()` method has low time complexity like a [Set](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-set/index.html).

Comment: Or, even shorter: `val filtered = locales.filter{ it.language in lang }`